# google app engine login jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine

This is for a class project. It has a jQuery mobile interface and a Python Google App Engine back end. One part of the requirement is to have user accounts.

One way to do this is with Google's built-in User type. I attempted this route first. I set up a $.get request to a handler on the App Engine. I simply wanted to console.log one message if the user was signed in, and a different one if they were not. If I logged in from my app engine page, it worked fine. If I did so from my web interface, it did not recognize the login.

So I switched to sessions using  "from webapp2_extras import sessions". I did this:

`

```
 class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self): 
        #Get a session store for this request
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)

        try:
            #Dispatch the request
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
        finally:
            #Save all sessions
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

    @webapp2.cached_property
    def session(self):
        #Returns a session using the default cookie key
        return self.session_store.get_session() `
```

and sent a get request to this:

`class LogInHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.session['user'] = "dude"
        self.response.write("just attempted to set session variable");`

using this JS request:

`function logIn() {
    $.get('http://my_app.appspot.com/login', {username : "dude", password : "doesn't_matter"}, function(data, status) {
        console.log(data); 
    });
}`

I then send a get to this handler:

`class ViewCollHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        user = self.session.get('user')
        if user: 
            self.response.write("There is a user!")
        else:
            self.response.write("No user!")`

Even if I first "login", I always get the response "No User!".

Again, this works fine if I access /login on my_app.appspot.com page. But if I send the get through my jQuery interface, it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong? Why does GAE recognize sessions and Google sign-ins from my_app.appspot.com, but not from http://my_ap.school.edu?

Comment: Logins on GAE using a custom domain may optionally require the user to use the same custom domain, not a general Google sign-in; while very dated, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/auth?hl=en -- that should not be the default setting but you may have accidentally set it.

Comment: Thank you I will check the settings.